# Should density plots and medians match?

Tags: statistics, median

I have a large dataset. I split the dataset into two parts (red and blue) and charted their density plots and medians (dotted lines) using R. Even though the density plot of the blue variable is farther to the right, its median is to the left. I removed outliers (defined as any observation that is more than 3 standard deviations away from the mean).

This does not make sense to me. Is this possible or have I made a mistake somewhere?

[image]

Comment: By what criterion do you judge "...[T]he density plot of the blue variable is farther to the right,"? Are you using the sample _mean_ for that? My guess is that removing what you judge to be 'outliers' may be contributing to the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Comment continued:  Here are two moderately large
samples from the same normal distribution.
In one sample the mean is larger than the median
and in the other the median is larger than the mean.
There's about a 50:50 chance that such a disparity would
occur by random chance.

```
set.seed(123)
x1 = rnorm(1000, 50, 7)
mean(x1); median(x1)
[1] 50.1129
[1] 50.06447
x2 = rnorm(1000, 50, 7)
mean(x2); median(x2)
[1] 50.29726
[1] 50.38397
```

As is characteristic of moderately large normal
samples, both have some boxplot outliers in
both tails. Deleting those might make the difference
between mean and median larger (mostly by changing
the sample means).

```
boxplot(x1, x2, col="skyblue2", pch=20, names=T)
```

[image]

Note: With long-tailed symmetrical distributions such as
Student't, Cauchy, and Laplace, the mis-match between sample means and medians might be even relatively larger.  For example:

```
set.seed(1234)
x1 = rt(1000, 5)
mean(x1);  median(x1)
[1] 0.00247168
[1] 0.001483836
x2 = rt(1000, 5)
mean(x2);  median(x2)
[1] 0.01859106
[1] 0.06574679

boxplot(x1, x2, col="skyblue2", pch=20, names=T)
```

[image]